# Determining divisibility of number by 11 for large numbers

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, division

I'm looking for a way to determine a large number is divisible by 11

My understanding:
(sum of digits at even positions - sum of digits at odd positions) % 11 == 0 ==> **yes**

This works for some examples.

Example: 
3816 => (3+1) - (8+6) = -10 
In case of negative, do we need to consider 2's complement of -10 for modulo % with 11?

Similarly: 391679 => 11 - 24 = -13 (this number is also divisible by 11)

Could you please help me understand this? thanks in advance.

Comment: So... you're saying that you're not allowed to use the modulus operator for some reason? `if((someLargInt % 11) == 0)` is a pretty clean way of getting what you want...

Comment: yes, problem statement is that number is very large and shouldn't use %

Comment: 10^0 = 1 mod 11, 10 = -1 mod 11, thus 10^2 = 1 mod 11, 10^3 = -1 mod 11, ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers 3816 and 391679 are not divisible by 11. Just validating the difference between the sum of alternate digits with %(modulo) 11 is enough to check divisibility by 11, even if the difference is negative.

Comment: My bad, thanks for confirming about negative number case.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to calculate small numbers which are divisible by Eleven, like 11, 22, 33, 121 and so on. But What about Large numbers? like 188452 or 31415 Yes, This is where we stuck.Let’s find A Number Divisible By 11 (Eleven) or Not

Here comes the easy way to calculate a number is divisible by Eleven or not. Just take the alternating sum of the digits of that number is the sum is divisible by 11 then the number also divisible by eleven.

Example ,

The number `N = 188452`

Alternating sum of the digits of N is `Sum = 1 – 8 + 8 – 4 + 5 – 2 = 0`

So, here `Sum = 0`, and we all know that 0 is divisible by 11.

Another Example ,

The Number `N = 31415`

Alternating sum of the digits of N is `Sum = 3 – 1 + 4 – 1 + 5 = 10`

So, here `Sum = 10`, and we all know that 10 isn’t divisible by 11.